# How do I iterate over methods for Perl object

Tags: perl, oop

I've created an Object such as

```
my $hex = Hexagram->new();
```

and it has various methods:

```
top
bot
chinese
title
meaning
```

This object will be created numerous times and each time I need to gather and test information for each of the above methods.

I would like to do something like

```
foreach my $method ( qw/top bot chinese title meaning/ )
  {
     &gather_info($hex,$method);
  }
```

and then have something like

```
sub gather_info {
  my ($hex,$method) = @_;
  print "What is the $method? ";
  my $response = <STDIN>;
  chomp $response;
  $hex->${method}($reponse);
  .... and other actions ....
  }
```

But this doesn't work.  Instead, for each method I seem to have to write out the basic code structure again and again which just seems plain wasteful.

I've also tried something where I try to pass a reference to the method call such as in

```
foreach my $ra ( [\$hex->top, "top"],
                 [\$hex->bot, "bot"],....)
  {
     my ($object_method, $name) = @{$ra};
     &rgather_info($object_method, $name);
  }
```

where

```
sub $gather_info {
  my ($rhex, $name) = @_;
  print "What is the $name?";
  my $response = <STDIN>;
  chomp $response;
  &{$rhex}($response);
  .... and other actions ....
}
```

But this time I get an error about

```
Not a CODE reference at <program name> line <line number>,....
```

Any suggestions on how I can do this?

Comment: What do you mean by "this doesn't work"? `$obj->$method(@args)` is valid Perl.

Answer (score 2):

According to [perlobj](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlobj.html#Method-Call-Variations) method calls can be made using a string variable.

```
$object->$method( @args );
```

So your `foreach` loop should have worked fine.  Or this one, which is much less wordy:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my $hex = Hexagram->new();
gather_info( $hex, $_ )
    for qw/top bot chinese title meaning/;

sub gather_info {
    my ($hex, $method) = @_;

    print "What is $method?\n";
    my $response = <STDIN>;
    chomp $response;
    $hex->$method( $response );
}
```

Make sure you have `strict` and `warnings` enabled and try again.  Update you post with errors, etc.